# Magento SOAP error

Tags: soap

everytime i run this

```
   $proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
   $sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'admin', 'apiKey' => 'admin'));
   $result = $proxy->customerCustomerCreate((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'customerData' => ((object)array(
   'email'      => $email,
   'firstname'  => $firstname,
   'lastname'       => $lastname,
   'password'       => $auto_password,
   'website_id'     => '0',
   'group_id'       => '1'
   ))));   
   var_dump($result->result);
   }
```

i get this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in add-new-customer.php on line 2
```

I'm running this on the latest MAMP. I also tried running this on the 'native' mac php/apache and it runs without any problems. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self explanatory - the second line is not valid, more specifically the login method needs 2 strings, one for username, one for password but you are calling `(object)` against an array and using the result as the method argument.  Try with just:

```
$sessionId = $proxy->login($username, $password);
```

Where `$usename` and `$password` are strings.

Comment: No luck, this is what I got:

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Procedure 'login' not present in add-new-customer.php:2 Stack trace: #0 add-new-customer.php(2): SoapClient->__call('login', Array) #1 add-new-customer.php(2): SoapClient->login('theusername', 'thepassword') #2 {main} thrown in add-new-customer.php on line 2 `

Comment: You are probably going to be better off looking at something like [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/) to give you a more complete picture on the subject.  Be here all day otherwise giving you debugging hints.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely take a look at that. I'm pretty new to Magento, SOAP and etc. But I got the above example to work by switching to 'SOAP V2' instead of 'SOAP V2 (WS-I Compliance Mode)'